# Jquery hide() / show() on window width

Tags: jquery

Hi guys please advise if this is the correct way of running the code on certain window width.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
var width = $(window).width();
if(width <= 780){
  jQuery(".answers").hide();
  jQuery(".container h4").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).next(".answers").siblings(".answers:visible").slideToggle();
    jQuery(this).next(".answers").slideToggle();
  });
}

else{
    jQuery(".answers").show();
}
})
```

on width bigger than 700px if I click on the question.. the whole thing keeps wobbling. Please advise --- the Jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/bw6k874b/28/

Comment: Do you need to do it via JS? Why not do it via CSS? Way better performance-wise. Wobbling is caused by elements being initially hidden and each time the window is resized, if the width is bigger than 780px, they will get shown.

Comment: Here is some help, without the wobbling: https://jsfiddle.net/e4g4a4m2/

Comment: I'm doing through Js because I want the answer div if the user clicks on some other div.

Comment: thanks @Mazz .. That was exactly what I wanted

Comment: Nice, i added it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to check with `jQuery(".answers").is(':hidden')` if `.answers` is already hidden.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var width = $(window).width();
if (width <= 780) {
    if (jQuery(".answers").is(':hidden')) return; // This is the fix
    jQuery(".answers").hide();
    jQuery(".container h4").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next(".answers").siblings(".answers:visible").slideToggle();
        jQuery(this).next(".answers").slideToggle();
    });
} else {
    jQuery(".answers").show();
}
})
```

Here is yours without the wobbling:  https://jsfiddle.net/e4g4a4m2